# Unable to upgrade and install WhatsApp

Tags: google-play-store, updates, google-account, whatsapp-messenger

I didn't check WhatsApp in a few days, so I tried clicking into it, I got a message like "This version of WhatsApp became obsolete on `<specific date>`. Please go to the Play Store to download the latest version".

I clicked the upgrade button and was led to the Google Play Store where I was told to sign into my Google account, but it didn't allow me to.

I uninstalled WhatsApp and rebooted my phone. I tried downloading WhatsApp and I'm still told to sign into my Google account.

Comment: Just login to google play store with your email. If you can't, please be clear as to what is the problem.

Comment: Could you tell us more about the device which you are using? The model name and OS version?

Comment: A quick solution while issue with google account is unresolved, download newest apk from `apkmirror` and install it. Enable unknown sources in setting first.

Comment: What Android version are you using? You could be using an old version of Android that WhatsApp no longer supports.

Answer (score 0):

Download it from the site instead: http://www.whatsapp.com/android/

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

- First go to settings-> Find google play store -> Clear Cache, Now Reboot your Phone.
- Again go to Settings -> Account -> Add New account [If there is no active google account], Add your Gmail ID and Password - Sign In.
- Now go to Play Store-> It will automatically add your Gmail account, Find Whats app in Play store-> Download it, Hope that works!
- Even if it not works, then you can download whatsapp from the whatsapp website. [Link is there in the below comment, Follow it].

  Check this links too:

1) https://www.androidpit.com/forum/459499/can-t-sign-in-to-google-account

2) http://forums.androidcentral.com/general-help-how/346959-solved-can-t-log-my-google-account-my-samsung-galaxy-s2-plus-gt-i9105.html

Answer (score 0):

Just remove your old account from Settings > Accounts , and add it again and then try upgrading your whatsapp.